# Linker error on GLFW on linux (x11)

Tags: c++, linux, x11, glfw, vulkan

I just installed GLFW3 on Ubuntu and I'm testing the example code from the documentation (http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) and I got those errors.

I tried multiples thing like adding -ldl, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the error log (GCC):

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/Game obj/Debug/main.o  -ldl -lglfw3 -lm -lGL -lGLU  
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(vulkan.c.o): In function `_glfwInitVulkan':
vulkan.c:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `dlopen'
vulkan.c:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `dlsym'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(vulkan.c.o): In function `_glfwTerminateVulkan':
vulkan.c:(.text+0x382): undefined reference to `dlclose'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(vulkan.c.o): In function `glfwGetInstanceProcAddress':
vulkan.c:(.text+0x72f): undefined reference to `dlsym'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `translateKeyCode':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `XkbKeycodeToKeysym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `XkbKeycodeToKeysym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `XGetKeyboardMapping'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `createKeyTables':
x11_init.c:(.text+0xc3e): undefined reference to `XkbGetMap'
x11_init.c:(.text+0xc61): undefined reference to `XkbGetNames'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x137f): undefined reference to `XkbFreeNames'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1395): undefined reference to `XkbFreeKeyboard'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `hasUsableInputMethodStyle':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x14b2): undefined reference to `XGetIMValues'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x150c): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `getSupportedAtom':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x155b): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `detectEWMH':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x15ea): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1610): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1678): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x16a1): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x16ad): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x16be): undefined reference to `XFree'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x16ca): undefined reference to `XFree'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o):x11_init.c:(.text+0x190d): more undefined references to `XFree' follow
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `initExtensions':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x194e): undefined reference to `dlopen'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1993): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x19c1): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x19ef): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1a1d): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1a8b): undefined reference to `dlopen'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1ad0): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1afe): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1b56): undefined reference to `XQueryExtension'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1bdf): undefined reference to `dlopen'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1c24): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1c52): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1c80): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1cae): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x1cdc): undefined reference to `dlsym'
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o):x11_init.c:(.text+0x1d0a): more undefined references to `dlsym' follow
//usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): In function `initExtensions':
x11_init.c:(.text+0x214a): undefined reference to `dlopen'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x218f): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x21bd): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x21eb): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x220d): undefined reference to `dlopen'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x2252): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x2280): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x22ae): undefined reference to `dlsym'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x23b4): undefined reference to `XkbQueryExtension'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x23f3): undefined reference to `XkbSetDetectableAutoRepeat'
x11_init.c:(.text+0x2420): undefined reference to `dlopen'
```

Comment: usually this kind of error is related to LD_LIBRARY_PATH -or- perhaps you need a -L to give path to library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Order of libraries when linking matter. If library A depends on library B, then A must come *before* B on the command line.

In your case, since the `glfw3` library depends on the `dl` library, you must switch order so that `glfw3` comes before `dl` on the command line.

You also must link with the `X11` library.

So the full command line should look something like

```
g++ -o bin/Debug/Game obj/Debug/main.o -lglfw3 -ldl -lm -lGL -lGLU -lX11
```